# Slick carousel right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I've setup slick carousel to continuously scroll, however I need to to scroll in the oposite direction. Adding the RTL option didn't seem to work.

Fiddle here (currently left to right)

**http://jsfiddle.net/mth2ghod/**

```
 $(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({

        speed: 10000,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 100,
        cssEase: 'linear',
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        variableWidth: true

    });
});
```

Comment: See https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/2968. Mentioned "Slick Slider not working in Arabic #3702" So it seems not working on RightToLeft Languages Like Persian and Hebrew too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the slidesToScroll to a -1 (it will change the slide direction)

```
 $(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
       speed: 10000,
       autoplay: true,
       autoplaySpeed: 100,
       cssEase: 'linear',
       slidesToShow: 1,
       slidesToScroll: -1,
       variableWidth: true

    });
});
```

Comment: If I use `slidesToScroll: -1` my slider breaks completly, is there something that has changed since?

Comment: @Loosie94 You right. The issue on GitHub Not answered yet: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/2063

Answer (score 18):

Setup "slidesToScroll" property to a negative value (e.g `slidesToScroll: -1,`) is not a native solution. This produced images smooth flow problem.

The right way is to add an attribute `dir="ltr"` to the slider's container (HTML element) OR add `rtl: false` property to slider settings:

```
// add an attribute dir="ltr" to the slider's container
//$('.slider').attr('dir', 'ltr');

// OR add `rtl: false` property to slider settings

$('.slider').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  rtl: false
});
```

Note: This will reverse text direction also which can be changed by the CSS `direction: ltr;`

[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/cyborg_b/nr2pe7t3/8/)

Comment: Thanks mate! I missed the `dir="rtl"` part. This answer must be the correct answer, or at least get more votes, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words @hayatbiralem,
You pay me attention to this post, and I made a small correction in the code example.

Answer (score 7):

in your rtl css add below without any edit on

> [dir='rtl'] .slick-slide {
>       float: left; }

Comment: An explanation of your answer would be nice.

Comment: This only solves issue if you keep centerMode true, check this example if you turn off CenterMode:false then it will not show the current sequence.. sequence in this template shows as 7,6,5,4,1 and you will notice slide 2 & 3 will only show once you click the arraow or autoplay... https://themeflex.com/strucflex/ar/

Comment: @Bila Talal : Thank you so much. After lot's of struggle, finally found your solutions is fit to me and your suggestions are working perfect..

Answer (score 2):

know this is old, but the slick docs says:

Note: the HTML tag or the parent of the slider must have the attribute "dir" set to "rtl".

Answer (score 2):

This works for me,

I add `( dir="rtl" )` to the slider container and then add `( rtl: true )` to the slick slider settings

```js
$('.carousel-rtl').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrow: true,
    dots: true,
    rtl: true,
  });
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slide-wrapper">
    <h2>Slick with RTL<h2>
    <div class="carousel-rtl" dir="rtl">
      <p>0</p>
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the sample here
https://codepen.io/davecar21/pen/RwovWvB

Answer (score 1):

None of these worked for me, `slidesToScroll: -1` and `rtl: true` just killed the carousel. But then Karl Maw pointed out the simplest solution:
Just use `CSS` to flip the carousel `180` and its content another `180`.

```css
.carousel {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.carousel__item {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example for **vertical** slider from top to bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/mth2ghod/114/

```
$(function(){
$('.slider').slick({

    speed: 5000,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 0,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: -1,
    vertical: true

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Slick GitHub page the bug fix is the below CSS code:

```
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: left;
}
```

and

```
.slick-slider .slick-track, .slick-slider .slick-list {
direction: ltr;
}
```

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/2968#issuecomment-1143535266

Answer (score 0):

**Slick Carousel RTL and LTR**

Example: **English (LTR)** and **Arabic (RTL)**

Slick Carousel for RTL:

```
$(".slider-nav").slick({
    arrows: false,
    fade: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    rtl: true
});
```

Slick Carousel for LTR:

```
$(".slider-nav").slick({
    arrows: false,
    fade: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    rtl: false //not mandetory in LTR
});
```

Answer (score 0):

adding [dir="ltr"] to the slider container and also adding [rtl: false] to slick slider settings fixed the issue for me.

Example code:

```
this.$hero.slick({
      accessibility: true,
      arrows: false, // this theme has custom arrows
      draggable: false,
      dots:true,
      fade: false,
      rtl: false,
      autoplay: this.$hero.data('autoplay'),
      autoplaySpeed: this.$hero.data('speed')
    }).slickAnimation();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Slick carousel right to left then Remove the dir="rtl" from slick slider main div and also remove rtl: true from the jquery part.

```
dir="rtl" /* Remove from slick slider div
rtl: true  /* Remove line from slick slider jquery
```

> **For Example:**
>
> https://codepen.io/davecar21/pen/RwovWvB